# Identify female vocal country/rock song when search for lyrics yielded no exact matches - "you say I won't forget you"?

Tags: identify-this-song, rock, country

I'm trying to identify a song which the lyrics say something like "you say I won't forget you" // "you say that I don't love you" (something like that, I was at the gym and couldn't write it down or record with my phone).

The voice is a strong female vocal, reminiscent of Amy Winehouse or Mary Chapin.

It is a fairly fast-paced, country/rock style song (more modern rock/pop than country, but a hint of "twang"), lead instrument is probably electric guitar plus maybe piano/synth back-up with lots of studio stuff added (I'm not a musician, so this could be off-base). Based on the rythm and overall style and the fact I only heard it once or twice before, I would say it's a "modern" song from within the last few years.

Lyrics searches have led me to *Brandy - U Don't Know Me*, unfortunately although the written lyrics look promising, the actual song is nothing like what I heard. Quite a few other matches also are totally wrong. Perhaps it's a re-interpretation of some old lyrics? The song is stuck in my head, please help!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it includes plenty of potentially identifiable details --unless it's just a protest against the entire "identify-this-song" category...

Comment: Maybe it's a protest against the artists mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mystery song was *Prayer in C* by *Lilly Wood & The Prick* - *Robin Schulz re-mix*. I see now that I mis-heard half of the words, making it much harder to identify!